Type 'T' is generic and can only be indexed for reading.ts(2862)
I am trying to write a TypeScript function to create fields on demand. Here is what have so far:
export function lazy_field<T extends Record<string,unknown>,FIELD>(
  target:T,
  name:string,
  init:()=>FIELD
){
  const exists=target[name]
  if (exists!==undefined)
    return exists
  const new_val=init()
  target[name]=new_val
  return new_val
}

My problem is that the line target[name]=new_val has this error:
Type 'T' is generic and can only be indexed for reading.ts(2862)

What is this error about and how do I fix it? tsconfig.json is blank.

tartget[name] = ... is writing, not reading. You're changing the type of the argument, which isn't a type-safe thing to do. Also afterwards the new field won't be accessible anyway: https://tsplay.dev/NanLpm

@jonrsharpe yes, that is intentional, the idea is to write to the fields when it does not exists

@jonrsharpe the idea is to use it like so https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwDYCGAXgJ4D6CmweAJgDwAqcoMwKNAznAErBrT0OMKJhQBzADSoA1iggB3FAD4JcAGJKAFACg4cGAShjgMAFxwGE3XBQEAtsHNCR4q3tGYzcTQEo4AXiV1bR9zNTgAb2t+FCFmEEwhLn99Q2MYAG1bBwBdAG5rTARvUESYLgBCfxTUGmBKFGAaPyi9PSgTJChcUqSCvQBfaJw4xvkyADcCPAC4DxhfftSjEyz7YBzZscnppY6YLtxtqbwCodFWKAQCNGA4AFkATRgSMGBWxAgIU2dRSWsAEbEAD8phQSDsAOAUG0QxicW+Txeb1mEU+3zgACIgVBMXABgVtIRSBQqLRNBBVNjiJjVL4AkEAIwAJgAzD4CvCIHhgAA6PAQMQU3lAogc7RAA

Then don't you want something like https://tsplay.dev/WzXBQN? Note it won't actually change the type of the first argument, to make the property non-optional.

@jonrsharpe's comment is correct, he should write an answer (or find a dupe target) if yigal agrees that it fully addresses the question.

both @Nikos Paraskevopoulos and jonrsharpe  answers are excellent, and solve my question perfectly, thank you so much!

Check out this:
export function lazy_field<T, K extends keyof T, FIELD extends T[K]>(
  target: T,
  name: K,
  init: ()=>FIELD
){
  const exists=target[name]
  if (exists!==undefined)
    return exists
  const new_val=init()
  target[name]=new_val
  return new_val
}

Roughly it says that "for a type T and where K is a key of that type and FIELD is the type of T[K]". Your playground example seems to work with this. Sometimes Typescript needs a specific choreography to understand what you want to do with its types, but is very strong in the end.
